# constructing a weighted penalty function as function of position for elastic net

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am solving a "special" elastic net like regularized least squares problem

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_2 + \lambda_1 {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} + \lambda_2 {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{2} $$

where I'd like to use previous knowledge and prefer more to have the  $L_1$ regularization at some region vs $L_2$ in another. For example, if solving for $x$ yield a vector of length 100, I know that in the first 40 elements the solution is strictly sparse (only 2-3 non zero elements), and in the other 60 elements it is smooth (some distribution). How would I transfer that into the optimization? can I create a smooth crossover region?

I thought of separating the problem to two problems where I use some threshold on $A$, for example, I copy $A$ into two arrays:

`A1=A; A1=A(41:end,:)=0` ,    `A2=A; A2=A(1:40,:)=0`

and then solve two optimization problems that are independent with $L_1$ norm minimization for $A1$ and $L_2$ for $A2$ . I would like to have a weighted crossover region where the penalty is elastic net-wise (such as `tanh(x-x0)` from $L_1$ to $L_2$). any advice on how to accomplish that? (I use CVX)

Edit:

Following Peter K. comment (if I understand what you meant), consider a position weighting function $f=\frac{1}{2} \tanh(\frac{ x-x_0}{ \delta})+\frac{1}{2}$ , a smooth step like function with some width $\delta$ and its application via:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_2 + \lambda_1 {\left\| (1-f(x)) \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} + \lambda_2 {\left\| f(x) \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{2} $$

The idea is that for $x<x_0$ we will mostly use the $L_1$ penalty, for $x\sim x_0$ it will an elastic net like combination, and for $x>x_0$ it will be the $L_2$ penalty. Does that make sense?

Comment: Interesting question.  Can you explain a bit more about how you see the elastic penalty working?  I don't think splitting the underlying $A$ the way you suggest is the best approach. I suspect it's better to modify the $\left\|x\right\|_p$ terms to be $\left\|w_px\right\|_p$ where the $w_p$ are some window functions and $p=1,2$.

Comment: I edited the question and added more info following your comment. thanks.

Comment: is the matrix $ \boldsymbol{A} $ a square matrix?

Comment: yes (but comments need to be 15 characters long)